# Why DROP TABLE doesn't seem to take effect before a SELECT INTO?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

The following tSQL query is puzzling me:

```
select 1 as FIELD into #TEMP
drop table #TEMP
select 1 as FIELD into #TEMP
```

When I run it from SQL Server Management Studio session window (pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> to the whole query, as a group), I get the following error:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   There is already an object named '#TEMP' in the database.

Note that table `#TEMP` doesn't exist before the query is executed.

I thought that the code shouldn't produce any errors as line 2 is dropping the temporary table. But it is as if the drop isn't taking effect when line 3 is executed.

My questions:

1. Why does the error happen?
2. How do I fix the query so it executes as intended?

PS. The query above is a simplification of a real world query of mine that is showing the same symptoms.

PS2. Regardless of whether this is a sound programming practice or not (as Sean hinted in his comments), this unexpected behavior prompted me to look for information on how these queries are parsed in the hopes that the knowledge will be helpful to me in the future.

Comment: It has to do with the way the sql compiler and parser work. The question I have is why in the world would have the same name for a temp table inside a single procedure??? That sounds like a recipe for confusion to me.

Comment: You could add `GO` after your first `drop table` to indicate the end of a batch, but if this is actually part of a stored procedure, it won't work, and even if it's *not* in a stored procedure, Sean's comments still apply.

Comment: @Sean - That's a good point. Actually, that's what I ended up doing anyway - using a different name for the temp table. But I was intrigued by the issue, that's why I asked.

Comment: @Sean - I though that the INSERT INTO would resolve the existence of #TEMP object at runtime, but that's not the case, is it? A co-worker hinted that the objects may be resolved at compile time, but I don't understand exactly how it all works in this case. Do you have any hints as to why this works like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I found the seek of existing tables are different:

```
select 1 as FIELD into #TEMP
drop table #TEMP
```

When you use `into` statement after those commands:

```
select 1 as FIELD into #TEMP
```

Error is:

> There is already an object named '#TEMP' in the database.

And When you use a `select` on `#TEMP` after those commands:

```
select * from #TEMP
```

Error is:

> Invalid object name '#TEMP'.

So, In first case THERE IS an object with `#TEMP` name and in the other case THERE IS NOT an object with `#TEMP` name !.

An important note from `technet.microsoft` is:

> DROP TABLE and CREATE TABLE should not be executed on the same table in the same batch. Otherwise an unexpected error may occur.

---

In notes of dropping tables by SQL Server Database Engine:

> The SQL Server Database Engine defers the actual page deallocations, and their associated locks, until after a transaction commits.

So the second error on using `select` statement may related to **the actual page deallocations** and the first error on using `into` statement may related to **duration between lock associated until the transaction commits**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand the issue now. The note you cited from technet.microsoft is specially helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here try this:

```
select 1 as FIELD into #TEMP
drop table #TEMP
GO
select 1 as FIELD into #TEMP
```

Comment: I've tried that, but the problem then is that all context (variables) is lost after `GO`. But that's helpful, thanks!