# drop temp table but already founded 'There is already an object named '#temp' in the database'

Tags: sql-server-2012, temp-tables

in part of code need to make swap between two temp table when i make drop one table and reuse it i can't

```
create table #temp (id int)
create table #swap (id int)

drop table #temp

select * into #temp from #swap

drop table #swap
drop table #temp
```

i receive this error

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   There is already an object named '#temp' in the database.

Comment: [Why DROP TABLE doesn't seem to take effect before a SELECT INTO?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29465648/5070879) You need to add `GO` after second CREATE TABLE and  first DROP TABLE

Comment: i can't use `GO` because this code part of while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change out your logic flow a little. If all that matters is that `#temp` is empty when the `INSERT` happens, this should do what you need.

```
create table #temp (id int)
create table #swap (id int)

<Add loop logic here>

truncate table #temp

insert #temp(id)
select id from #swap

<Close out loop logic>

drop table #swap
drop table #temp
```

I also made the column names explicit. `SELECT *` is an accident waiting to happen in production code.

Comment: Thank you but i need to know why i can't do @EricBrandt

Comment: From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): `DROP TABLE and CREATE TABLE should not be executed on the same table in the same batch. Otherwise an unexpected error may occur.` As is noted in the question linked to in a comment above. The `INTO` clause generates a `CREATE TABLE` in the background in the same batch as the `DROP`, and you get the noted error.