# SELECT INTO fails if used more than once - even if table is dropped first

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I've run into a frustrating error using SELECT INTO in Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4-GDR). (I'm using SSMS 18.12.1 to run the query, but run into the same error using different query tools.)

The following example demonstrates it:

```
--First, create a small table with some dummy data
CREATE TABLE Foo (
    Luke varchar(10),
    Leia varchar(10),
    Han varchar(10)
)
INSERT INTO Foo (Luke, Leia, Han)
VALUES  ('Blah','Nope','Yeeha'),
        ('Test','123','Yep');

--SELECT INTO then DROP (first time)
SELECT * INTO ##Temp1 FROM Foo;
DROP TABLE ##Temp1;

--SELECT INTO then DROP (second time)
SELECT * INTO ##Temp1 FROM Foo;
DROP TABLE ##Temp1;
```

Obviously, the desired result is just that this code runs to completion -- but I get this error (which applies to the second attempt to SELECT INTO on line 14):

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
> *There is already an object named '##Temp1' in the database.*

The issue arises whether I use global temporary tables (##Temp1) or local temporary tables (#Temp1) ***but*** works as successfully when selecting into an ordinary local table.

I do have permission to create and drop temp tables. If I run each step of the query individually I have no problems. Ditto if I state GO after each step of the query. But to run it as one batch fails.

Forcing a delay between the first DROP and second SELECT INTO doesn't help.

This is rather baffling. Is it a bug in SQL Server 2012 or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This is not a bug; you're not supposed to recreate a table in a single batch because the optimizer can't draw up the query plans. In older versions of SQL Server, this failed even for regular tables. Due to how deferred compilation works, you occasionally get away with it anyway, but not for temporary tables (which have even more complicated rules for scoping and when one table is considered the same as another). Basically, T-SQL really wants schemas to be static, and (potentially) changing table structures on the fly makes that very complicated.

Comment: Not quarreling with the question, but couldn't you create `##Temp1` and do an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` into it?

Comment: Also, you might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28944223/why-drop-table-doesnt-seem-to-take-effect-before-a-select-into?rq=1

Comment: For a global temp table specifically you might be able to get away with using `EXEC` to perform (some) inserts in a separately compiled batch, but this gets messy quickly.

Comment: Thanks @Jeroen Mostert - that sounds reasonably definitive. It never ceases to amaze me how quickly I can get a technical answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Add a DROP TABLE IF EXISTS at the beginning and separate the code in different batches with the GO statement

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##Temp1;
GO

CREATE TABLE Foo (
    Luke varchar(10),
    Leia varchar(10),
    Han varchar(10)
)
INSERT INTO Foo (Luke, Leia, Han)
VALUES  ('Blah','Nope','Yeeha'),
        ('Test','123','Yep');
GO

--SELECT INTO then DROP (first time)
SELECT * INTO ##Temp1 FROM Foo;
DROP TABLE ##Temp1;
GO

--SELECT INTO then DROP (second time)
SELECT * INTO ##Temp1 FROM Foo;
DROP TABLE ##Temp1;
GO
```

Comment: `DROP IF EXISTS` doesn't exist in (the completely unsupported) SQL Server 2012. It was added in SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Thanks @Wouter. As I said, I can run the query successfully as separate batches - In my case I am keen to run it as a single batch and wondering why it is giving an error for temp tables, especially as it works fine when selecting into an ordinary database table